# Amazon Connect: How to create a new contact flow instance from Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp for business

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-messenger, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I know that Amazon Lex bots can be included inside a Contact Flow in Amazon Connect and that Lex bots can link to Channels including Facebook Messenger but I’m unsure how to initiate a new Contact Flow instance from a new Facebook user connecting via Facebook Messenger or similar via Twilio WhatsApp API. Chat has only just been added to Amazon Connect so might not yet be supported directly so open to external solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Channels' (FB, etc.) in Lex are unfortunately totally separate from Amazon Connect and not integrated. In order to use Amazon Connect Chat with something like FB or WhatsApp currently, you have to use a solution that uses the Chat websockets API - you can see a similar solution [here](https://blogs.perficient.com/2020/04/02/using-sms-with-amazon-connect-chat/) that was used to integrate SMS to Connect Chat.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar kind of integration between WhatsApp and Amazon Connect months back, using Twilio's WhatsApp Business API -
https://github.com/tamdilip/whatsapp-amazonconnect-chat

Believe you were looking for the same.